# dotnet core 3.1 Authorization Cognito user groups claims issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been tried different ways to use "cognito:groups" claim, but none of them are working.

Here's my code

services.AddCognitoIdentity ();

```
        services.AddAuthorization (options => {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder (JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser ()
                .Build ();
            options.AddPolicy (Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_ADMIN, policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups", Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_ADMIN));
            options.AddPolicy (Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_USER, policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups", Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_USER));
            options.AddPolicy (Constants.AWS.Cognito.ALL_USER_GROUPS, policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups"));
        });
```

What I want to do is have 3 authorize policies, one for admin users only (working fine), one for normal users only (working fine) and one for both user groups (doesn't work), how can I achieve that? I've also tried RequireAssertion, and it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this policy :

```
options.AddPolicy (Constants.AWS.Cognito.ALL_USER_GROUPS, policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups")
```

will only check if the claim `cognito:groups` is present for the identity - it will not check the value of that claim at all.

if you wanna have a policy that checks if that claim to have two values, you should add this kind of policy:

```
options.AddPolicy ("USER&ADMIN", policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups", Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_USER).RequireClaim ("cognito:groups", Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_ADMIN));
```

And then to apply it just use:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "USER&ADMIN")]
```

Comment: Didn't aware I could change them together, will give it a try, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to check the claim has two values, I want to check if the claim has either of those two values

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check admin or user role try this:

```
options.AddPolicy (Constants.AWS.Cognito.ALL_USER_GROUPS, policy => policy.RequireClaim ("cognito:groups", Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_ADMIN, Constants.AWS.Cognito.USER_GROUP_USER))
```